# Concurrent Doubly Linked List - Multiple Producer/Consumer FIFO Queue - Deadlock

Tags: c++, deadlock, producer-consumer, doubly-linked-list

I was playing around with a doubly-linked list for a MPMC FIFO-Queue (mainly for demonstration purposes). I aim now trying to pin down my mistake for a while and I do not really make progress.

I run into a deadlock, shortly after all Producer-Threads have produced all values. I pinned down the problem to the following:

Lock Acquisition:

```
<THREAD ID> | <MESSAGE> | <MUTEX ADDRESS>

4460175360 : TRYLOCK HEAD:   0x7fb380c039d0
4460175360 : LOCKED HEAD:     0x7fb380c039d0
4460175360 : RELEASED HEAD: 0x7fb380c039d0

4460175360 : TRYLOCK HEAD:    0x7fb380c039d0
4460175360 : LOCKED HEAD:      0x7fb380c039d0
4460175360 : RELEASED HEAD:  0x7fb380c039d0

4460175360 : TRYLOCK HEAD:    0x7fb380c039d0
4460175360 : LOCKED HEAD:      0x7fb380c039d0
4460175360 : RELEASED HEAD:  0x7fb380c039d0

4460175360 : TRYLOCK HEAD:    0x7fb380c039d0
4459638784 : TRYLOCK TAIL:       0x7fb380c039d0
4460711936 : TRYLOCK TAIL:       0x7fb380c039d0
4460175360 : LOCKED HEAD:      0x7fb380c039d0
4460175360 : RELEASED HEAD:  0x7fb380c039d0

4460175360 : TRYLOCK HEAD: 0x7fb380c039d0   <---- THIS TRY-LOCK-HEAD NEVER GETS CONFIRMED!
4459638784 : LOCKED TAIL:  0x7fb380c039d0 
4459638784 : RELEASE MUTEX: 0x7fb380c039d0 <---- THE PRODUCER THREAD RELEASED 0x7fb380c039d0
Producer-Thread 4459638784 produced: 0

---- NOW ONE ELEMENT IN QUEUE ----

4460711936 : LOCKED TAIL:  0x7fb381800020 <---- ADDRESS OF LOCK HAS CHANGED WHICH IS FINE (because an element has been added)
4460711936 : RELEASE MUTEX AT ADDR: 0x7fb381800020
Producer-Thread 4460711936 produced: 0

---- NOW TWO ELEMENTS IN QUEUE ----

4460711936 : TRYLOCK TAIL: 0x7fb381a00020
4459638784 : TRYLOCK TAIL: 0x7fb381a00020
4460711936 : LOCKED TAIL:   0x7fb381a00020
4460711936 : RELEASE MUTEX AT ADDR: 0x7fb381a00020
Producer-Thread 4460711936 produced: 1

---- NOW THREE ELEMENTS IN QUEUE ----

4459638784 : LOCKED TAIL: 0x7fb380d00060  <---- AGAIN ADDRESS HAS CHANGED -- FINE
4459638784 : RELEASE MUTEX AT ADDR: 0x7fb380d00060
Producer-Thread 4459638784 produced: 1

---- NOW FOUR ELEMENTS IN QUEUE ---- PRODUCERS ARE DONE ----
---- CONSUMER THREAD BLOCKS - STILL TRYING TO LOCK 0x7fb380c039d0 ----

---- BUT NOBODY ELSE HOLDS 0x7fb380c039d0 ---- ALSO NO SELF-DEADLOCK?
```

GDB tells me that both producer threads have terminated, and the only thread waiting for the mutx at addr 0x7fb380c039d0 is thread 2 (the only consumer thread):

```
    (gdb) info threads
* 2                         0x00007fff8edc5dfd in pthread_mutex_lock ()
  1 "com.apple.main-thread" 0x00007fff8e715386 in __semwait_signal ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff8e715122 in __psynch_mutexwait ()
#1  0x00007fff8edc5dfd in pthread_mutex_lock ()
#2  0x00000001000011a8 in ConcurrentDoublyLinkedList<int>::consumeNode (this=0x1001000e0) at ConcurrentDList.h:142
#3  0x0000000100000bd4 in consumeValues (ctx=0x7fff5fbffa78) at ConcurrentDList.cpp:29
#4  0x00007fff8edc07a2 in _pthread_start ()
#5  0x00007fff8edad1e1 in thread_start ()
(gdb) f 2
#2  0x00000001000011a8 in ConcurrentDoublyLinkedList<int>::consumeNode (this=0x1001000e0) at ConcurrentDList.h:142
142             pthread_mutex_lock(&head_->mutex);
(gdb) info reg
rax            0x200012d    33554733
rbx            0x100281000  4297592832
rcx            0x100280da8  4297592232
rdx            0x100    256
rsi            0x403    1027
rdi            0x1001039f0  4296030704
rbp            0x100280ed0  0x100280ed0
rsp            0x100280e00  0x100280e00
r8             0x2060   8288
r9             0x100280720  4297590560
r10            0xf9d79  1023353
r11            0x206    518
r12            0x1303   4867
r13            0x0  0
r14            0x7fff5fbffa78   140734799805048
r15            0x100000bb0  4294970288
rip            0x1000011a8  0x1000011a8 <ConcurrentDoublyLinkedList<int>::consumeNode()+110>
eflags         0x206    518
cs             0x7  7
ss             0x0  0
ds             0x0  0
es             0x0  0
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x0  0
(gdb) p *(pthread_mutex_t*) 0x1001039f0
$34 = {
  __sig = 1297437784, 
  __opaque = "\000\000\000\000` \000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\003\004\000\000\000\002\000\000{?\017\000\000\000\000\000\b:\020\000\001\000\000\000\f:\020\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot insect pthread_mutex_t because it is an opaque type. (Although I have opaque types turned on within GDB?). Otherwise it would be good to see who the owner of that mutex currently is.

The code of my list is given below - it is excessively commented, to explain my thoughts on the implementation. Note that this is by far not a good or high-performance implementation - its mainly for illustration purposes.

CPP-Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <pthread.h>

template <class T>
class Node
{
    private:
       T value_;

       Node<T> *next_;
       Node<T> *prev_;

    public:

        pthread_mutex_t mutex;

        Node(T value, Node<T>* next, Node<T>* prev)
        {
            value_ = value;

            next_ = next;
            prev_ = prev;

            pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
        }

        ~Node()
        {
            pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
        }

        void setNext(Node<T>* next)
        {
            next_ = next;
        }        

        void setPrevious(Node<T>* prev)
        {
            prev_ = prev;
        }

        Node<T>* getNext()
        {
            return next_;
        } 

        Node<T>* getPrevious()
        {
            return prev_;
        }


        virtual bool isSentinel()
        {
            return false;
        } 
};

template <class T>
class SentinelNode : public Node<T>
{
    public:
      SentinelNode(T val, Node<T>* next, Node<T>* prev)
          : Node<T>(val, next, prev)
      {
      }

      virtual bool isSentinel()
      {
          return true;
      }
};

template <class T>
class ConcurrentDoublyLinkedList
{
    private:
        Node<T> *head_;
        Node<T> *tail_;

    public: 
        ConcurrentDoublyLinkedList()
        {
            head_ = tail_ = new SentinelNode<T>(NULL, NULL, NULL);
        }

        void produceNode(Node<T>* n)
        {  
            pthread_mutex_lock(&tail_->mutex);

            Node<T>* old = tail_;

            if(head_->isSentinel())
            {
                head_ = tail_ = n;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&old->mutex);

                delete old;
                old = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                n->setNext(tail_);
                tail_->setPrevious(n);
                tail_ = n;

                pthread_mutex_unlock(&old->mutex);
            }
        }

        Node<T>* consumeNode()
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&head_->mutex);

            if(head_->isSentinel())
            {
                 /* the head can only be a Sentinel if there is
                  * no element within the list
                  */

                  /* this also means that the list is currently
                   * implicitly fully locked */

                  /* return NULL and let the thread decide what to do */

                  pthread_mutex_unlock(&head_->mutex);

                  return NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                /* the head is not a Sentinel, which implies on of the following:
                 *     - The list has exactly one element, which means:
                 *         => head_ == tail_ && !head_->isSentinel()
                 *     
                 *     OR
                 *     
                 *     - The list has at least two elements, which means:
                 *         => head_ != tail_ && !head_->isSentinel()
                 *
                 *     - The absence of a Sentinel guarantees that the list
                 *       is NOT empty
                 */

                 if(head_ == tail_)
                 {
                      /* single element within the list 
                       * the list is still fully locked, 
                       * implicit because head_ == tail_
                       */

                       /* we replace the only element
                        * with a Sentinel, because
                        * the list is empty afterwards
                        */

                        Node<T>* p = head_;
                        head_ = tail_ = new SentinelNode<T>(NULL, NULL, NULL);

                        pthread_mutex_unlock(&p->mutex);

                        return p;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                      /* at least two elements are in the list
                       * which means that the current head
                       * must have a valid predecessor 
                       */

                       /* Producer and Consumer could
                        * hold a lock on two adjacent
                        * nodes. Thus, the Consumer
                        * must acquire head->prev
                        */

                        Node<T>* p = head_;
                        Node<T>* n = head_->getPrevious();

                        pthread_mutex_lock(&n->mutex);

                        /* head_->prev can now not be owned 
                         * by a producer. 
                         */

                        head_ = n;
                        head_->setNext(NULL);

                        pthread_mutex_unlock(&p->mutex);
                        pthread_mutex_unlock(&n->mutex);

                        return p;
                 } 
            }
        }
};
```

I would really appreciate your thoughts and ideas on that stuff. I am looking at it for a while now and could also be totally on the wrong path. Help is appreciated..

Thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: For starters, lose the concept of sentinel nodes. They're very-rarely ever needed and this is no exception to that. NULL is as good a sentinel as anything else, and significantly reduces the list management complexity. In this case, yours is leaking as soon as you add a new node to the list. I.e. once the list goes from empty-to-note, the sentinel is leaked.

Comment: OK - but we could also just decide to deallocate it properly (code is edited) !? Using Sentinel nodes makes lock acquisition of empty lists quite easy, so I don't see the "significant" reduction in list management complexity...

Comment: I guess you're right. So long as the bugs are fixed, its not really significant. And "we" didn't write that leak, so it was even less significant on this side.

Answer (score 0):

The consume and produce both lock the head and tail nodes assuming that the nodes are still head and tail afterwards. That is, the threads may have locked nodes that are no longer head or tail nodes. If you stored an "old" pointer before locking, you would at least know which node you locked, but the locked node may already have been consumed, and some of your logic may no longer hold.

I think it would be easier to lock the head and tail pointers, rather than actual nodes, assuming you only need produce and consume methods. Of course, the simplest solution is to lock the entire data structure.

Comment: do you have an example of this situation? I cannot see how this invariant should be violated. If the head is locked it cannot be consumed by any other thread and is either replaced by a sentinel or sets the predecessor as new head (which cannot be changed by any producer nor by any other consumers -- since locked). If a producer locks the tail, and it is not a sentinel, than it can only change something if the tail is at least the third element within the list. How would you express your doubts in form of lock acquires?

Comment: I have the feeling that the problem is indeed around the situation that you are mentioning... but I still can't see the invariants broken that I assume...  Can you provide an example?